# Download JDK version

Tags: java, rhomobile, rhodes

i have just finished downloading and installing rhostudio from the below link
http://rhomobile.com/products/rhostudio/

and second step is to download JDK but the below link is so confusing and i dont know what to click since i am running on my windows 7 64 bit

Download JDK version 1.6.0_2 or higher from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and then install it on 32bit Windows machine

any help? i am looking to download JDK as it says above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the newest JDK, you should download Java Platform (JDK) 7u1.

Click on the button, which says this.

On the new page, scroll down and download the one for Windows x64 (should be 80,24MB).

Download and run the .exe. If you don't change the path during the InstallationWizard, JDK should be installed to the default path:

C:\Program Files\Java(\jdk1.7xxxx\bin) The part in the brackets might be irrelevant.

I don't know if that answers your question, but I hope I could help.

Comment: which says what? i think you forgot to write the line `Click on the button, which says this.`

Comment: I meant: You should click the button which says : "Java Platform (JDK) 7u1"